# Error saying 'Not enough values to unpack Expected 2 got 1'

Tags: python

```
tambola_callout = {}
for line in open("bingo-call-out.txt"):
    num, callout = line.split(";")
    tambola_callout[num] = callout
```

don't know what the problem, what can I do?

Comment: Did you try checking what the value of `line` is when the error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
num, callout = line.split(';')
```

is expecting that your call to `split` will return a list of exactly two elements. Python will error out if you try to unpack too few or too many values during an assignment.

For example, this will return a single element list:

```
'something'.split(';')  # == ['something']
```

Make sure your string is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

it simply means that one of the lines in your file `bingo-call-out.txt` has the format of `<all characters here>` instead `<some characters here>;<some characters here>`

What this error means is that in a general scenario, suppose line = `abcd;efgh`

`line.split(";")` will return an array of two elements `[abcd,efgh]` which will be assigned to`num` and `callout` respectively.

Now if there is a line = `abcde`, so line.split(';') is returning just `['abcde']` which is a single element list, which can be unpacked into 2 variables like your syntax intends to.